# Cases of creating instance in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have just learnt inheritance and polymorphism, in C#, and I am confused between these 3 cases. You can create an instance when we have a base and derived class.

Could you please explain the differences (Especially Obj1 with Obj2)?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Shape     obj1 = new Shape();
        Shape     obj2 = new Rectangle();
        Rectangle obj3 = new Rectangle();

    }
}

class Shape
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

class Rectangle : Shape
{
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It makes very little sense to create a Shape object, [look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Shape obj1 = new Shape();
```

obj1 is a shape. It has Property1 and Property2. It doesn't have a Property3.

```
Shape obj2 = new Rectangle();
```

obj2 is a `Rectangle` that was downcast to a `Shape` the moment you instantiated it. If `Rectangle` overrides any `Shape` behaviours (which it doesn't in your example) then the `Rectangle` behaviours will be called at runtime, rather than the behaviours of the base `Shape` class. It has a `Property3` that it could use in its internals, but you can't access it from this method because it's already down-cast to a `Shape`.

```
Rectangle obj3 = new Rectangle();
```

obj3 is `Rectangle`. You can access `Property3` from this method. You can pass it to any method that requires a Shape because a `Rectangle` is a `Shape`.

I recommend that you write some more code along these lines and debug it in a simple console app to see what happens in different circumstances. Personally, I find that learning by doing is the best way.